# thick waveform in oscope

Tags: noise, oscilloscope, waveform

I built an oscilliscope with ARM and internal ADC (Atmel), but my signal is very thick (noisy). It looks like [this link](http://www.picotech.com/applications/mains-power-analysis.html), but sometimes worse!

Could the ADC be outputting noisy values?
What could be some possible reasons?
What are steps I can take to resolve this issue?

I should also mention that the maximum frequency is 25kHz.

Can a special capacitor resolve this problem?

Also, I would appreciate suggestions on how to chose a DAC and optimal frequencies.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I think you mean to say ADC - an analog to digital converter. You need to link the exact DAC you are using as well as your design and schematic. Can you tell me why my car leaks? Exactly.

Comment: yes my mean is ADC, but someome try to correct my dialoge thanks but some data losted...also SFBE(sorry for bad English)

Comment: @HL-SDK is it coming from the head gasket LOL

Comment: This seems maybe obvious, but did you make sure your scope probe is grounded?

Comment: Also note that the periods of a periodic analog signal will never be sampled exactly the same way twice. Not unless you lock your sampler to a trigger based on the signal.

Comment: Can you post a link to the original tutorial?

Answer (score 5):

You have noise on your signal, but we can't tell which of the many possible sources of noise are dominant.  The most likely is poor grounding the analog signal not treated properly on your digital board, but there are many others, including the input signal.  How do you know that signal doesn't really have that noise on it?

To eliminate the input signal, use two 1 kΩ resitors as a voltage divider to make half the supply voltage and then feed that into the A/D.  Put a 1 µF or so ceramic cap right at the A/D input pin with the other end directly to the analog ground pin on the processor.  For good measure, add a 100 µF or so electrolytic cap too.  That should give you a good clean signal at mid-range.  If that looks good, then something upstream of the A/D is making a mess or the source signal you are trying to measure is noisy.  If it is noisy with this test, then you are doing something wrong in firmware.

Keep in mind that ±1 count should be expected.

Comment: Poor ADC reference decoupling could be an issue as well.

Comment: i got it....this is error of my adc. and this err maybe becuse of my bad adc configuration adc...